Can I define a node preference for each task?
So here is my scenario:
Let's say I have 3 nodes in my batch pool. I submit 1 job with 9 tasks.
I want task 1,2 and 3 to be executed one after each other on the same node. The same goes for task 4-6 on the second node and task 7-9 on the third node.
However, this should be just a preference instead of a dependency, because for example if node 3 would finish the 3 tasks very quickly, it should still be able to execute one of the remaining tasks.
I did not find any way to define something like this in Azure Batch. Does any of you have an idea how I could still achieve this?
I did read about the task dependencies that one could define. However, this would on the one hand not guarantee that the tasks will be executed on the same node (at least I think so, for example if two nodes finish their tasks at the same time) and on the other hand I would not have the chance to distribute remaining tasks in the end, if one node has free capacities.

Maybe I did found a solution myself already.
You can add a affinity_info in the TaskAddParameter() class, which is a affinity_id of a compute node. The documentation says that this is a soft affinity.
So this might be exactly what I am looking for, but I still have to test how it will behave in my use case.

Yes, you are right, you can define a node preference for each task in Azure Batch by using the affinity_info property in the TaskAddParameter class. This property specifies an affinity ID of a compute node and provides a soft affinity for the task to run on that node. In your case, you can set the affinity_info property for tasks 1-3 to the affinity ID of the first node, tasks 4-6 to the affinity ID of the second node, and tasks 7-9 to the affinity ID of the third node. This will provide a soft affinity for the tasks to run on the specified nodes, but if those nodes are not available or do not have the required resources, the tasks will still run on other nodes.
To achieve the preference of running tasks on the same node in Azure Batch using the Python SDK, you can utilize the AffinityInformation class to specify task affinities. This is indeed a "soft" preference, not a strict binding, which means the scheduler will attempt to run the task on the preferred node but may choose another if needed.
Example:
from azure.batch import BatchServiceClient

from azure.batch.batch_auth import SharedKeyCredentials

from azure.batch.models import AffinityInformation, CloudTask, TaskAddParameter

  

# Replace with your Azure Batch account information

batch_account_name = 'arkobatchaccount'

batch_account_key = 'AEmh96NDGbJsfAMrar4gvEbu6w75X37BySs88QuFeUmrzdRiJ9lGj55uOqevd9uJ'

batch_account_url = 'https://arkobatchaccount.eastus.batch.azure.com'

  

# Authenticate with the Azure Batch service

credentials = SharedKeyCredentials(batch_account_name, batch_account_key)

batch_client = BatchServiceClient(credentials, batch_url=batch_account_url)

  

# Assuming you have already submitted an initial task and have its ID

initial_task_id = 'your_initial_task_id'

  

# Get the node ID where the initial task ran

task_info = batch_client.task.get('your_job_id', initial_task_id)

node_id = task_info.node_info.node_id

  

# Create an affinity to prefer running new tasks on the same node

affinity = AffinityInformation(affinity_id=node_id)

  

# Now, when adding new tasks, specify the affinity information

task = TaskAddParameter(

id='new_task_id',

command_line='cmd /c echo Hello world!',

affinity_info=affinity

)

  

# Add the task to your job

batch_client.task.add('your_job_id', task)

  

# Continue this process for subsequent tasks

Here I am setting up an affinity based on the node where a previous task was run. You would replace 'your_job_id', 'your_initial_task_id', and 'new_task_id' with your actual job and task IDs and replace with your Batch service credentials and URL.
Reference:

Azure Batch SDK Example
Jobs and tasks in Azure Batch - Tasks


Thank you for this nice example.  It does work perfectly fine like that.
But I do have an additional question:
If I create a new pool and the new nodes are not yet up and running and I directly want to queue some tasks with a certain affinity for those nodes, this is not working because I get only the affinity id for existing nodes.
Is there also a way to achieve the same as mentioned above, even before the resizing of the pool is finished?

Affinity IDs are specific to nodes that are already up and part of the pool and are typically used to create a soft preference for task placement on existing nodes. You can script your system to delay the submission of tasks until after the nodes have been initialized and their affinity IDs are available. This would involve monitoring the pool's state and only submitting tasks once it's confirmed that the nodes are ready

Perfect. I exactly solved it like you said, I monitor the pool status before I submit my tasks.
But I recognized another issue:
I always tought that if a node finished one task, "the node will decide", which task to process next and will do this based on the affinity.
But I just realized, that it works the other way around. It will always be decided from the "task perspective". So the task that is sheduled first, will always be executed first and the affinity just helps if more than one node would have capacities at that time.

Can this somehow be changed? So to say I would like the node to "pick" its next task based on affinity and ignores the scheduling order of the tasks.

In Azure Batch, the functionality for a node to autonomously "pick" its next task based on affinity, disregarding the overall scheduling order, is not supported directly through the service's built-in mechanisms. Azure Batch's scheduler primarily operates by assigning tasks to nodes based on the order of task submission and overall resource availability, with affinity acting as a secondary factor to guide placement when options are available.
